# How To Use android:largeHeap:true In API <= 10 in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, heap-memory, heap-dump

how to use
    android:largeHeap:true
In **AndroidManifest.xml** cIn API Level 10 And Bellow ?
It Defined In API 11 And Above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That attribute did not exist prior to API Level 11, and there is no documented and supported way of requesting a large heap prior to API Level 11.

Also, note that there is no guarantee that you will *get* a large heap even on API Level 11+ devices.

Comment: @RedReactor: "there is no guarantee?" -- correct. It is up to device manufacturers as to what you get when you request a large heap, and on some low-RAM devices, you may get the same size heap as you would have had without the flag. Moreover, there is no guarantee how "large" the large heap will be.